# How to change UITableviewCell background color on swipe action in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

**--------------------- Here is my code ---------------------**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let important = importantAction(at: indexPath)
        //let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath)

        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [important])

    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func importantAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction
    {


        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (action, view, completion) in


            completion(true)
        }
        action.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "checked_wht")
        action.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return action
    }
```

Comment: you need to change swiping cell background color or all cell?

Comment: what do you mean by swipe action? something like "swipe to delete"? or just a swipe on the cell's view?

Comment: only perticuler cell

Comment: means related to swipe action button cell

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func importantAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction
{
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (action, view, completion) in
        completion(true)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.row, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
    }
    let cell:UITableViewCell = (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)))!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    action.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return action
}
```

Comment: its not like that

Comment: when i click swipe action then that cell background color changed

Comment: see my func name importantAction

Comment: if that func called then cell background color changed

Comment: hello jigar its working but when  I scroll tableview multiple cell background changed

Comment: I do'nt like that untill and unless once again I reload table or run agin don't change color